# I need а private key

Tags: bitcoin-core, private-key

I generated a BTC address in "Bitcoin Core" before 2 years ago, but my HDD is burnet and I lost everything.

Unfortunately I don't saved file "wallet.dat" and I don't have "private key", but I have "passphrase". 
I install diferent versins on "Bitcoin Core", but I can only add BTC address and don't can make transaction.
I added my wallet address in "blockchain.com", but to make a transaction I need a "private key"
How can I get a "private key"?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. You need the wallet.dat file, unfortunately. Without a backup there is way to recover the funds.

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately, you're out of luck. If you didn't save the private key and didn't save the `wallet.dat` file, there is no way to perform a transaction. Your passphrase is useless without the `wallet.dat` file.